# Grunt-injector - Inject parent directories first

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, filesystems

I'm using `grunt-injector` and I have a list of files being injected using `'app/**/*.js` but I don't want to inject the files alphabetically as it is causing dependency errors. I want to systematically inject the files in the parent directory, then move to the next level and inject those files and so on. This way I will inject all the parent files first and remove any dependency issues.

Can anyone help to do this? I've tried looking at `grunt-include-source` as it includes a `top-down` file sort which is what I want but I was unable to get that working and I'd rather stick with injector as its used heavily at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, so I had to do changes in the injector.js script (node_modules/grunt-injector/tasks/injector.js).

You have to do:

1.- looking for the comment **"Sort files if needed"** and add an else case:

`else {
    //parent dir's files go first.
    if (options.parentDirFirst) {
       sources.sort(function (a, b) {
          return a.file.split("/").length - b.file.split("/").length;
       });
    }
 }`

2.- in your gruntfile.js you have to set the option **parentDirFirst** to true:

```
injector: {
    options: {
        parentDirFirst: true,
        .
        .
        .
    },
    .
    .
    .
}
```

these changes could be sent to Joakim Bengtson. He needs contributors to maintain the plugin, he's looking for people who want to help out and be contributors, but I don't have enough time.